# Pandas simplify adding aggregate columns (average, sum, count, max) in one step like with groupby.agg()

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data similar to:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   '1' :[7, 8, 2, 3, 0],
                   '2' :[1, 0, 4, 9, 9],
                   '3' :[3, 1, 1, 6, 8]})

   ID  1  2  3
0   1  7  1  3
1   2  8  0  1
2   3  2  4  1
3   4  3  9  6
4   5  0  9  8
```

and I want to add an Av, Sum, Count and Max column for each row for the values in columns 1, 2 and 3. Currently I am doing this like this:

```
cols = ['1', '2', '3']
df['Av'] = df[cols].mean(axis=1)
df['Sum'] = df[cols].sum(axis=1).fillna(0)
df['Count'] = df[cols].count(axis=1).fillna(0)
df['Max'] = df[cols].max(axis=1).fillna(0)

   ID  1  2  3        Av  Sum  Count  Max
0   1  7  1  3  3.666667   11      3    7
1   2  8  0  1  3.000000    9      3    8
2   3  2  4  1  2.333333    7      3    4
3   4  3  9  6  6.000000   18      3    9
4   5  0  9  8  5.666667   17      3    9
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do this neater/in 1 or 2 lines like with `groupby().agg()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) with list of functions:

```
df = df.join(df[cols].agg(['mean','sum','count','max'], axis=1).fillna(0).convert_dtypes())
print (df)
   ID  1  2  3      mean  sum  count  max
0   1  7  1  3  3.666667   11      3    7
1   2  8  0  1       3.0    9      3    8
2   3  2  4  1  2.333333    7      3    4
3   4  3  9  6       6.0   18      3    9
4   5  0  9  8  5.666667   17      3    9
```

With `rename` columns:

```
d = {'mean':'Av', 'sum':'Sum','count':'Count', 'max':'Max'}
df = (df.join(df[cols].agg(list(d.keys()), axis=1).fillna(0)
                                  .convert_dtypes().rename(columns=d)))
print (df)
   ID  1  2  3        Av  Sum  Count  Max
0   1  7  1  3  3.666667   11      3    7
1   2  8  0  1       3.0    9      3    8
2   3  2  4  1  2.333333    7      3    4
3   4  3  9  6       6.0   18      3    9
4   5  0  9  8  5.666667   17      3    9
```

Another idea:

```
d = {'mean':'Av', 'sum':'Sum','count':'Count', 'max':'Max'}
df = df.join(pd.concat({v: df[cols].agg(k, axis=1).fillna(0) 
                                      for k, v in d.items()}, axis=1))
print (df)
   ID  1  2  3        Av  Sum  Count  Max
0   1  7  1  3  3.666667   11      3    7
1   2  8  0  1  3.000000    9      3    8
2   3  2  4  1  2.333333    7      3    4
3   4  3  9  6  6.000000   18      3    9
4   5  0  9  8  5.666667   17      3    9
```

Comment: Thanks for this. My actual data is ~200,000 rows (for 4 columns) and using this is significantly slower than my method, would that be expected?

Comment: @EmiOB - It is reason because `agg` is general, faster is loop by dict.